# Making the z-buffer attend to axis lines

Tags: pgfplots

If I use centered axis lines, they don't seem to be considered worthy by the z-buffer. Surfaces get drawn on top of them, even when they should be behind them - like this:
[image: hidden axis]

Code used:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis equal,
            axis lines=center,
            scale uniformly strategy=units only,
            view/h=40,
        ]
        \addplot3[%
            patch,
            opacity=0.8,
            z buffer=auto
        ]
        coordinates { (0,1,0) (1,1,1) (-1,1,1) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do I have to draw transparent axes first, then the objects behind them, then add a new axis environment and eventually draw all the objects in front of the axis lines or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

***EDIT:*** I ended up playing z-buffer myself and manually drawing over the axis lines, like this:

```
\draw[line width=.275] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0,0,2.55);
```

But this gets quite annoying when having to enlarge axes so you don't have occluded arrow tips, splitting plots in a back and a front part to be able to redraw the axis line inbetween, ...
There has to be a better solution.

Comment: search for `axis on top` option. Though it won't solve every indivudual case.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want the axis to be rendered on top of the rest, but where it "should be". For example, if there's a plane behind the axis and a semi-transparent plane in front of the axis, the axis should be visible, but kind of "dimmed" where the front plane is. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation of `pgfplots`; there is no work-around (compare the reference manual section "Before You Start With 3D").

You can resort to `axis lines*=left` such that the effect is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`tikz-3dplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot).

#### Example

[image: Example]

Here you can see the *x*-axis to “leeve” the surface at the right position.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,fill opacity=.5]
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
{sqrt(15/2)/2*sin(\tdplottheta)^2}{black}%
{2*\tdplotphi - 6 * \tdplottheta}{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,2,0) node[anchor=south east]{$y$};}%
{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
\tdplotshowargcolorguide{3}{-.2}{.1}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks really nice, but the only real 3dplot supported is `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot`. You can't plot in cartesian coordinates. Only some special cases of polar functions. Thank you anyway, we're getting closer. :)